# JavaScript 2d game objects collision

Tags: javascript, oop, collision-detection, 2d-games

I'm currently learning JavaScript and I have a project to make a 2d rogue like game but I'm kind of stuck right now.

I created the room layout based on a map string with the following code:

```
import ImageTile from "/src/game/imageTile.js";
import Position from "/src/util/position.js"
import Wall from "/src/objects/wall.js";
import Skeleton from "/src/objects/skeleton.js";
import Door from "/src/objects/door.js";

class RoomBlueprint extends ImageTile {

    constructor(position) {
        super(position);
    }

    static createLayoutFromRoomString(roomString) {
        const lines = roomString.split("\n").filter(line => !line.trim().startsWith('#'));
        const layout = [];

        for (let y = 0; y < lines.length; y++) {
            const line = lines[y];
            const tiles = [];

            for (let x = 0; x < line.length; x++) {
                const char = line[x];
                const position = new Position(x, y);

                if (char === "W") {
                    const wall = new Wall(position);
                    tiles.push(wall);
                } else if (char === "0") {
                    const door = new Door(position);
                    tiles.push(door);
                } else if (char === "S") {
                    const skeleton = new Skeleton(position);
                    tiles.push(skeleton); }
                // } else if (char === "B") {
                //     const bat = new Bat(position);
                //     tiles.push(bat);
                // } else if (char === "k") {
                //     const key = new Key(position);
                //     tiles.push(key);
                // } else if (char === "G") {
                //     const badGuy = new BadGuy(position);
                //     tiles.push(badGuy);
                // } else if (char === "H") {
                //     const hammerPosition = new Hammer(position);
                //     tiles.push(hammerPosition);
                // } else if (char === "m") {
                //     const meat = new Meat(position);
                //     tiles.push(meat);
                // }
            }
            layout.push(tiles);
        }
        return layout;
    }
}


export default RoomBlueprint;
```

And now I need to create the collisions so my little hero don't just disappears. I've been searching for methods for collision but they don't seem to fit well here, since I'll have to add other options like Doors changing from close do to open, item picks, etc.

Can I somehow use this method I've created for the map blueprint to adapt it to check for collision between hero position and enemies/items/doors positions?
And also, was there another way to fetch the room layout? A more simple way?
On my engine file, I run this method with:

```
        this.layout = RoomBlueprint.createLayoutFromRoomString(room0);
        this.layout.forEach((tiles) => {
            this.gui.addImages(tiles);
        });
```

Comment: Generally speaking you could compare the `Position` of the player with the `Position` of all the obstacles. For example `for (obs of obstacles) {if(obs.position == player.position {...}}`